# a/the maximum speed of 100

Tags: articles

I wonder in which context these two would be fitting.

> The car was going at the maximum speed of 200 mph.
>
> or
>
> The car was going at a maximum speed of 200 mph.

Usually, it's "a" but I think there are situations in which "the" is correct. What are they?

Comment: If the official speed limit is 200, I would say "at **the** maximum speed". If it is the car's own limit, then "at **its** maximum speed. The maximum speed is particular, not general, so I would not use the indefinite article.

Comment: 'At a maximum speed of 200 mph' - at speeds up to and including 200 mph.

Comment: @Weather Vane "at the maximum speed" is another kettle of fish. The question is focused of ""at ___ maximum speed of 200mph"

Comment: @Kate Bunting Do you mean that "the maximum speed of 200 mph" is always wrong?

Comment: Edit: If the *official* speed limit is 200 mph, I would say "The car was going at **the** maximum speed of 200 mph." If it is the car's *own capability*, then "The car was going at **its** maximum speed of 200 mph." The maximum speed is particular, not general, so I would not use the indefinite article.

Comment: No, _the maximum speed_ means what Weather Vane says.